# Is there a way to verify user's auth token in Firebase Security Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Something similar to 
`admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)`
in Security Rules.

Or is it unnecessary (perhaps, because Firebase would automatically perform the verification before moving on to the security rules)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unnecessary.  The decoded token is available in [request.auth.token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth), if one was provided by the client.

Comment: I am thinking about foregoing authentication using Cloud Functions entirely and just using Security Rules. So, on the client's end, the client may modify custom claims to something they are not; does Security Rules rely on client's provided token (and custom claims), or does it verify before use, or does it skip client's custom claims entirely and bring them out from the User Database?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Your rule determines if the request is granted. If you require a token, code it that way. There are examples in the docs for security rules.

Comment: I have Custom Claims in my auth token. A user with malicious intent may temper with the auth token before making a request (that he is not supposed to make). What I'd like to know is, does Firebase automatically deal with such (corrupt) tokens? If not, is there a way to verify the integrity of the token in Security Rules?

Comment: What you're proposing isn't possible. It validates the token on every request. What you get is guaranteed to be correct.